# set the whole interpreter as UTC in python

Tags: python, utc

I want to make sure that a whole script is using by default only UTC. Any idea how to do that? I have been looking for solutions, but somehow not found anything working. Really all what I want is to make sure that:

```
import datetime
# SOME CODE HERE
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Does print 1970-01-01 00:00:00, on any machine, without more trouble, and that everything is treated as UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
import datetime
import time
import os

os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC"
time.tzset()

print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: That works, so many thanks :) I had been trying to get this to work for half an hour, I had found the ```os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC"``` on other threads, but I was missing the ```time.tzset()``` line ^^ .

Answer (score 5):

If you ensure that the environment variable `TZ` is set **before** importing `datetime`, then it is not necessary to use `time.tzset()`.

For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["TZ"] = "UTC"
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

In order to avoid editing your Python script, you can just set the environment variable when executing it.  For example in the Linux command line:

```
env TZ=UTC python myscript.py
```

Comment: Aaah, interesting, this is why many of the answers I found before only had the ```os.environ``` line I guess :) I think I like better the answer by L3viathan though, as it is more robust, in the sense that if for whatever reason some other modules are imported before, they should be forced to move to UTC, right? :)

Comment: @Zorglub29 I think the most **robust** solution is mabergerx's one, which does not rely on changing `TZ` at all. But your requirement appeared to be to make it work without having to change the code. (Unless I misunderstood, obviously.)

Comment: I do not think so, I really want to make sure the whole interpreter is in UTC forever in this session after that.

Comment: @Zorglub29 Okay understood - maybe I misunderstood what your "without more trouble" meant. Even so, it is clearly better - if you are in a position make the necessary changes to the code - to explicitly work in UTC by using `utcfromtimestamp` if that's what you want, rather than try to work around the fact that the code is instead calling a function which is documented as using local time. Both my solution and L3viathan's one are essentially just variants on such a workaround, based on slightly different understandings of how few changes you are willing to make.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a convenience function from `datetime` that was literally designed for this purpose, without the need to set up a timezone through other libraries:

```
from datetime import datetime
# SOME CODE HERE
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
# '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
```

However, if you would also need to have this UTC zone in other uses, say, third-party libraries, etc., then the solution with `tzset()` is probably more convenient :)

Comment: I know this function, but in this case only the present call is using UTC, right? What I want is to make sure that the whole interpreter is in UTC, for all the following.

Comment: Yeah true, I edited my answer to reflect on that :)